# How do I draw an ArrayList of Coordinates to Canvas? [Java]

Tags: java, canvas, arraylist

I'm trying to make the game artillery. To produce the Map I have been told by my lector to make a List of Y Coordinates that gets generated relatively randomly. Now I have this list(GameMap) but I can't seem to find a proper Canvas Method to draw them. Is Canvas just not the best way to work or is there a method to do this with? The length of this ArrayList is 1000+ big.

```
public class MapView extends StackPane {

private Canvas canvas;
private GraphicsContext graphicsContext;
private GameMap map;

    public MapView(){
        initialiseNodes();
        layoutNodes();
    }

    public void initialiseNodes(){
        canvas = new Canvas(250, 250);
        graphicsContext = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    }

    public void layoutNodes(){
        graphicsContext.setFill(Color.ALICEBLUE);
        graphicsContext.fillRect(75, 75, 100, 100);
        this.getChildren().add(canvas);
        for(Integer i : map){
            graphicsContext.
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your question how you want to display the coordinates, but is this the kind of example you're looking for?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DrawPoints extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        int width = 200, height = 200;
        Canvas c = new Canvas(width, height);

        /*
         * Some randomized list of points.
         */
        List<Point2D> points = new ArrayList<>();
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                points.add(new Point2D(rnd.nextInt(width), rnd.nextInt(height)));
            }
        }

        /*
         * Drawing them as points (1x1 filled rectangles) on a Canvas
         */
        for (Point2D p : points) {
            c.getGraphicsContext2D().fillRect(p.getX(), p.getY(), 1, 1);
        }

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().add(c);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response, it's kind of hard to show the code since I'm working in the MVP model. this is my view class, what i basically need to create is a game like (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/0a/Artillery_apple.png) [this] and the coordinates that i have would be a border for the map which gets randomly generated. The code to generate it randomly is in my model but drawing them in the view is where I have problems.